# Administrate gem raise error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I installed administrate gem. Opened /admin and it raise this error:

> Invalid CSS after "  alert": expected ")", was ": $light-yellow," (in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/administrate-0.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets/administrate/application.scss:45)

```
ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'

gem 'administrate', '= 0.1.5'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using administrate 0.1.5 for anything? Its github page recommend to install "~> 0.2.0"

Maybe your version of sass gems deprecated something and it is not reflected in your administrate version dependencies.

I recommend you to update to latest version as they say.

Comment: Ok i did it. It raise new error 
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:76:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /home/deployer/carespotter/current (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: @dmitriy_strukov I guess you updated Puma too.  Seems to be a closed issue related to it https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/904